# Standard .gitignore for Phonegap

Tags: git, cordova, gitignore

I am planning to submit a PhoneGap application on **GitHub** yet, I am having a hard time getting a standard/universal `.gitignore` contents.

Here's my tentative `.gitignore` file:

```
.DS_Store

# PhoneGap files and directories
hooks/
platforms/
```

All I know the `www/` is the one needed in order for the PhoneGap application to be built on various platforms. I wasn't planning to build or alter codes on the native language(s). So is the right or standard `.gitignore` contents for Phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a portion of mine:

```
*/platforms
*/plugins
*/hooks
*/.cordova
```

(The `*` is because the repo contains many Cordova projects, not just one.)

This essentially leaves the `www`, `config.xml`, and `merges` directories as the code that will be in the repo.

Comment: I see. Anyways, what's the purpose of `merges` folder?

Comment: It allows you to overwrite specific files in `www` with platform-specific files. For example, if you had a `index.html` file in `merges/android`, the Android project would receive the file in `merges/android` while all the other projects would receive the file in `www`. While useful, there are very few situations where it should be the first choice -- it would be better to detect the device in your code and react accordingly. But for the times when there is no option, `merges` can be useful. (Note: this directory may not exist, but if you need it, you can create it.)

Comment: I just use the www directory as a repository, and then issue 'ln -s www/config.xml config.xml' on an initialized phonegap demo app.